# what is the meaning if in where clause we have an other value

Tags: sql, flask-sqlalchemy

WHERE ("z" = 'abc')) "test"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to show the entire query, but `"test"` is not part of the `where` clause.  It looks like a table alias or a column alias.  For example:

```
select "test".*
from (select t.*
      from t
      where ("z" = 'abc')
     ) "test"
```

I do not advise escaping column aliases or table aliases, but your code seems to be doing that.